# Atualizar model pai quando o mesmo estiver como nested do Filho

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Estou criando um sistema onde o usuário cria uma proposta, na ficha de proposta ele deve inserir os dados do cliente que está numa tabela separada.

Isso está funcionando para criar a proposta, mas não para atualizar, pois da forma como estou apresentando abaixo, o erro "unknown attribute 'valor_oferta' for Customer" aparece. Segue meu código:

Tenho 2 models:

```
class Sale < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :customer, inverse_of: :sales

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :customer
end

class Customer < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :sales, inverse_of: :customer
end
```

Sale Controller:

```
class SalesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!

    def new
        @sale = Sale.new
        @sale.build_customer
    end



    def create
        @sale = Sale.new(proposta_params)

        respond_to do |format|
          if @sale.save
            format.html { redirect_to dashboard_path, notice: 'Proposta criada com sucesso.' }
          else
            format.html { render :new }
            @sale.errors.each do |erro|
                puts erro
            end
          end
        end

    end


    def edit
        @sale = Sale.find(params[:id])
        @sale.customer
    end


    def update
        @sale = Sale.find(params[:id])

        respond_to do |format|
          if @sale.customer.update(proposta_params)

            format.html { redirect_to dashboard_path, notice: 'Proposta alterada com sucesso.' }

          else
            format.html { render :edit }
            @sale.errors.each do |erro|
                puts erro
            end
          end
        end

    end



    private
        def proposta_params
            params.require(:sale).permit(:valor_oferta, :grupo_promocao, :codigo_oferta, :modo_pagamento, :vencimento, :banco, :agencia, :conta, :isento, :valor, :data_envio_qualidade, :data_agendamento_qualidade, :janela_agendamento, :data_instalacao_qualidade,:tv_id, :phone_id, :internet_id, :equipamentos, :cep, :rua, :numero, :complemento, :bairro, :cidade, :uf, :ponto_de_referencia, :obs, customer_attributes: [:name, :cpf_pf, :nascimento_pf, :nome_mae_pf, :nome_mae_pf, :cnpj_pj, :fundacao_pj, :telefone1, :telefone2, :telefone3, :email, :juridica])
        end
end
```

PS: Eu já tentei usar somente "@sale.update(proposta_params)", mas dessa forma ele cria um outro Cliente ao invés de atualizar

O campo VALOR_OFERTA faz parte de SALE e não do Customer.

Poderiam me ajudar por gentileza?

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei a solução

Ao invés de @sale.customer.update(proposta_params) devo usar @sale.update(proposta_params) e também ficou faltando adicionar o "id" do Customer no customer_attributes do metodo proposta_params

Comment: Por favor aceite sua própria resposta... ;)

Comment: Precisa de 2 dias, ainda não consigo aceitar. Obrigado por lembrar

Comment: Boa... Já me falaram isso - mas acho que eu nunca aceitei uma pergunta minha, então nunca sei! :p